# Navbar float left makes contents on same line

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sass

I'm trying to set up a sample website and I'm running into an issue with the section between header and footer getting put into the same line as the header

removing margin and padding resets as a wild card fixes this but there has to be another way.

Fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/P8QmL/
[image: Website]

```
header ul {
  display: inline; }
  header ul .nav-header li {
    list-style: none;
    margin-right: 1em;
    float: left; }
  header ul a {
    text-decoration: none; }

*{ margin: 0; padding: 0; }
```

Comment: please provide fiddle

Comment: Fiddle added to main post

Comment: changing ul to display:inline works on fiddle but not on my app in rails

Comment: Then make it !important

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question properly then this should help you

```
.nav-header li {
list-style: none; 
margin:  0 auto;
display: inline;
}

.nav-footer li{
list-style:none;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xLjX6/1/)

Comment: I agree this should work but it doesn't I had the same solution

Comment: * { margin: 0; padding: 0; } is also set